# How to enable communication between 'software' netplan configured vlans

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I have searched far and wide so I if it looks like I have no idea what i'm doing, that is because it is a correct assumpstion. Usually we do this ourselves with our MikroTik router setup. We have a machine network where each network needs to be separated into its own /24 subnet. In this particular situation because customer wanted to to the complete infrastructure this was done ad-acta where a network interface is connected to all subnets with each own VLAN.

Here is slightly shortened configuration:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
    enp4s0:
      gateway4: 192.168.79.1
      nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.11.5, 192.168.11.6]
      addresses: [192.168.79.114/24]
      dhcp4: false
  vlans:
   vlan.2008:
    id: 2008
    link: enp2s0
    macaddress: 00:00:00:00:20:08
   vlan.2010:
    id: 2010
    link: enp2s0
    macaddress: 00:00:00:00:20:10
  bridges:
   br2008:
    interfaces: [vlan.2008]
    addresses: [10.10.21.254/24]
    dhcp4: no
   br2010:
    interfaces: [vlan.2010]
    addresses: [10.10.31.254/24]
    dhcp4: no
  version: 2
```

ip tables config:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -o enp2s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br+ -j ACCEPT
```

The problem I have now is that for this example there are 'gateway aware?' 2 devices (10.10.31.10 on br2010 coming in at VLAN2010 and 10.10.21.15 on br2008). What do I have to do differently to get these two to be able to communicate with each other?

Currently I can ping 10.10.31.10 from br2010 and 10.10.21.15 from br2008, what routing do I have to do to get these two to see each other? In Mikrotik this is done without a hitch so what I am missing here? If this is done completely wrong I am able to change it except that devices need this VLAN configured, otherwise everything can be rearranged. What do I need to read on to know what is going on here better?